# How to add CSS-Class to a GoogleMaps marker?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to animate (fadein, fadeout) a marker in my GoogleMaps application (Web).

> How can i assign any css class to a marker?

Or how can i access the specific marker? Do they have selectors like :after or something?

If not, whats the easiest way of applying animations to them?

Comment: `the easiest way of applying animations` to markers is using the [Animation class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#Animation).  Unfortunately it doesn't include options for fading, it only lets you 'drop' or bounce them

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The DOMNode that contains the image used for the marker isn't available via the API.

Furthermore, by default the markers will not be single DOMNodes, they will be drawn via canvas.

But the Marker-Image may be accessible via CSS when you use a unique icon-URL for each Marker.

---

Sample(using jQuery):

```
<style type="text/css">
img[src^='http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png?i=']{
  opacity: 0.5
}
</style>
<script  type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var index=0;
        var mapOptions = {
          zoom: 14,
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.5498783, 13.425209099999961),
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
            mapOptions);

        marker=new google.maps.Marker({position:map.getCenter(),
                 map:map,optimized:false,
                 icon:'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png?i='+(index++)});

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseover',function(){
          $('img[src="'+this.icon+'"]').stop().animate({opacity:1});
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'mouseout',function(){
          $('img[src="'+this.icon+'"]').stop().animate({opacity:.5});
        });
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```

---

**How ist works:**

The sample uses a single image as Marker-Icon (http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png)

via CSS we apply a opacity. You may notice that there is a i-parameter inside the URL. This parameter will be used to make the img-src unique.

I use a variable which will be incremented to get a unique img-src:

```
var index=0;

//a few lines later:
icon:'http://www.google.com/mapfiles/marker.png?i='+(index++)
```

Now you'll be able to select the `<img/>`-element used for the marker, e.g. onmouseover/onmouseout via a attribute-selector.

When you wan't to use vanilla javascript you may use `document.querySelector` to access the image.

**Note:** you must set the `optimized`-option of the marker to `false` (this will force the API to render the marker as a single element)
**Demo:** [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/nBsh4/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/nBsh4/)

Comment: This helps a lot, many thanks! Is there any API for removing the markers? I see many Data maps which fade out their markers when they are gone. I've set a timer for a few seconds, after hat, i want to fade out the markers and then "marker.setMap(null)"

Comment: Not working with path like ../image.png. When i want to grab the marker through the javascript console in chrome, i'm getting back an empty array. I passing the marker through a function "remove_marker(marker)", and after a setTimeout, its getting removed. But i cannot access the marker without "this".

Comment: I used a variation of this method and instead of dynamically changing each url with a unique id, I used one icon for each marker "type" and one extra icon for the "active" marker of that type. When clicking on a marker, I dynamically change it's url to append "Active" at the end of the file name, and first reset any markers that previously had "Active" in their file name. (If you follow this method be sure to use the marker's .setIcon method to change the file path, not the .icon property)

Comment: As of Google Maps v3, you are no longer able to access custom image markers like this :(. Try going to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-simple and enter `document.querySelectorAll('img[src*=beachflag]')` in the console.

Comment: @10basetomWhy should I try, I know that my Demo works? Read my answer again and youl'll find the difference.

Comment: 9 years later and still works, thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick that can work if you for example want to change the cursor for the marker
Add this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(YOURMARKER,'mouseover',function(){$(".gm-style   div").addClass("markerClass")});                        
google.maps.event.addListener(YOURMARKER,'mouseout',function(){$(".gm-style div").removeClass("markerClass")});
```

and

```
#YOUR-CANVAS .gm-style div {cursor: default !important;}
#YOUR-CANVAS .gm-style div.markerClass{cursor:pointer !important}
```

works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is, select the marker and add a class the that selection.But for that you have to give each marker a title. Any animation would not work except google ones.

$("div[title=\"" + name+ "\"]").addClass("aClass")

I hope this helps someone.