# How can I change cluster icon on angular google maps?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm using angular google maps and I'm trying to use the cluster feature but it's not working, maybe some of u could give me a hint.

Here is a fiddle working but its with the default google cluster image (yellow, blue n red cluster), u can see 3 markers, if u reduces the zoom u will see the cluster.

http://jsfiddle.net/5ya0svjs/11/

```
$scope.clusterOpt = {
        calculator: function(){
            return { index: 1 , text: "HERE DUDE, CAN U SEE?", title:"Please help me guys"};
        },
        styles: [
            {
                url: "mypath/anyImage.png",
                width: 63
            }
        ],
        averageCenter: true
    };
```

I wanna customize it, so I've added the calculator function to return one of my own images based on how much markers is on the cluster. But when I do it the cluster is been on top of the map, not where it should be, I tried to set the avarege property and the anchor property but both is useless to solve this bug.

In this fiddle u can see the calculator function, returning always 1 for the styles array with only 1 makericoncluster (to be specific with the bug).
When you reduces the zoom u will not see the cluster where it should be, but u will see it on top of the map, I didnt put an image too, I only write a text "Here dude...") (to be specific with the bug). Could someone help me?

(if u click on the marker, that is only a "here dude, can u see?" u will be placed where markers are)

This is my [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5ya0svjs/14/)

Comment: Found a working [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/B3a86/2/) that may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `width`(and `height`)-properties of the cluster-styles do not scale the image, they clip the image. So in the example you'll only get the clipped part of the image(which is empty).

Use CSS to scale the image, e.g. via

```
.angular-google-map-container .cluster img {
  width:63px;
  height:93px;
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5ya0svjs/30/

Comment: The problem was that I didn’t saw that the height was a required property too, I thought that the required was listed at the bottom but there was another required property hidden there =(

With the height property it become okay. But thank you for the css reference for the image I wont need it cause the dimension of my image already the right one.

Comment: width  and height are not really "required", when they were this should force an error(because width and height are not set): http://jsfiddle.net/5ya0svjs/44/ ...but you'll  see the ClusterIcon

Comment: Here is written that it's required.
http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.16/docs/reference.html#ClusterIconInfo

But anyway, u solved my problem =D thank you.

Comment: Dr.Molle, u showed me the css to customize the cluster icon, that is
.angular-google-map-container .cluster img {
  width:63px;
  height:93px;
}

, I try to customize the icon in the same way, my image is a square n I want to set as a circle, I tried to use .angular-google-map-container .marker img , but it didnt work, do u know what should I use?

Comment: [example using an image as a circle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ya0svjs/49/) (via `border-radius:50%`)  . Note: when you draw a border around the marker you must reduce the width and height of the img(in the CSS) by borderWidth*2

Comment: Yep, I did it with the cluster already, but I didnt found a way to do the same with the marker (a normal marker).  There is no use .angular-google-map-container .marker img , so how could I do that?

Comment: Possible solution based on [**How to add CSS-Class to a GoogleMaps marker**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047466/how-to-add-css-class-to-a-googlemaps-marker/22049762#22049762) : [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/4dnfxbbs/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/4dnfxbbs/)(markers -> red border, clusters -> black border) . Note the `options`/`icon`-attributes for `<ui-gmap-markers/>`(you must e.g. define the clickable area via a [MarkerShape](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerShape)) .

Comment: I'm sorry for it Dr. Molle, but could you try to help me here?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29566931/how-to-customize-the-infoboxui-gmap-windows-style-for-angular-google-maps?noredirect=1#comment47288682_29566931

Its about customize google maps too.