# How to customize the infoBox(ui-gmap-windows) style for angular google maps?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'd like to know how to customize the ui-gmap-windows style, default is a blank white square, what about if I wanna a heart with a message inside? I know how to change the content of the ui-gmap-windows but how could I change the style?

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true" options="options">
        <ui-gmap-markers clusterOptions="clusterOpt" doCluster="true" models="markers" coords="'self'" icon="'icon'" idKey="'idKey'">
            <ui-gmap-windows <!--How to change style? --> >
                <div >Here I can change the content</div>
            </ui-gmap-windows>
        </ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

I fiddle would help so much =D

Comment: Have you tried using developer tools of your browser and looking for the element and its styles? Maybe you can override some css classes...

Comment: I tried but it was inline n added by javascript, so noway to overrride it (I think).
Could someone please help me? =(