# Google Map, styling not working on marker img with class but working with img[src]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I wants to style my marker which is a base64 string something like this [image]

I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367542/google-map-custom-marker-with-css-rounded-corner/25367993#answer-25371006) to achieve the desired result but this is only working when I am adding the whole source in the css like `img[src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0a9745ea7ac5c90d7acadb02ab....` [(fiddle which I found in above mentioned answer)](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/L2o2xwj3/) but when I am trying to target it with class, its not working anymore, I am adding the class after the map is loaded.

You can check the non-working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5raf237u/139/)

I have multiple markers with different colors in my map that's why I want to target with class, can anyone tell me the reason why its not targeting with class or is there any better way to do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add CSS-Class to a GoogleMaps marker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047466/how-to-add-css-class-to-a-googlemaps-marker)

Comment: Is the fiddle you provided it working "with the whole source in the css"? If so, could you provide a second fiddle with it not working using a class?

Comment: @AndrewM non-working fiddle is also there, I will write again http://jsfiddle.net/5raf237u/139/

Comment: Marker-Image may be accessible via CSS when you use a unique icon-URL for each Marker.

Comment: @BojanPetkovski icon-URL you mean src-url ?

Comment: @DanishAdeel Yes, as you can see from your example adding styles to `img[src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0a9745ea7ac5c90d7acadb02ab....` works, but not when using a class :)

Comment: @BojanPetkovski I have unique url for each icon but the problem is how to target them, I cant write each url in my css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of playing with google maps I found out that it actually embeds the icon 2 times on the map, so they are on top of each other. This is one solution to make it work with class, wrapping the img with div and adding the class to it.

```js
function initialize() {
 var mapOptions = {
  center : new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 160.644),
  zoom : 8
 };
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  map : map,
  position : map.getCenter(),
  shape : { coords : [17, 17, 18], type : 'circle'},
  icon : {
   url : 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0a9745ea7ac5c90d7acadb02ab1020cd?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1',
   size : new google.maps.Size(34, 34)
  },
  optimized : false
 })
 google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function () {
  setTimeout(function () {
     $('#map-canvas img[src="'+marker.icon.url+'"]').eq(0).hide();
     $('.gmnoprint > img').wrap( "<div class='in'></div>" );
  }, 200);
 });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html { height: 100% }
body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
#map-canvas { height: 100% }

.gmnoprint {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
.in {
  border-radius:16px;
  border:1px solid #000 !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.in img {
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution Bojan, but after implementation when I zoom IN/OUT I am getting errors in console.
Chrome:"util.js:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'size' of undefined"
FF:"TypeError: a.H is undefined util.js "